# Can I resolve "InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found" without adding anything to system PATH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, png, stringio, pydot

I am running the following code:

```
from io import StringIO
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(DT, out_file=dot_data,  
            filled=True, rounded=True,
            special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

and getting the following error message:

```
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Based on looking at other stackoverflow answers, it is my understanding that I can try to resolve this by adding things to PATH.

I do not have administrative rights (username and password) on my work computer so I was wondering if there is another way to resolve this error message?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but you could try [`set_graphviz_executables`](https://pydotplus.readthedocs.io/reference.html#pydotplus.graphviz.Dot.set_graphviz_executables) or modify the `PATH` variable in Python.

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'c:/path/to/dot.exe'
```